# Bootstrap moving image to top right corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started using bootstrap recently and I want to know if it is possible to make my image to the top right-hand corner of my page.

Currently, I only have like this: (I don't want to use padding)

```
<div id ="test" style="padding-left: 450px">
    @foreach($data3 as $currentUser)
        <img src="{{ url('images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}">
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I tried following here but still doesn't work, [How to place a div in the top right corner using Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806918/how-to-place-a-div-in-the-top-right-corner-using-twitter-bootstrap)

And I also tried using `class = "rounded float-right"` this also didn't work for me

Can someone help me here? Thanks a lot

Comment: why not using fixed position ?

Comment: you mean class="position-fixed"? I want it to be at the top right

Comment: im mean simply apply  some CSS to put it where you need `position:fixed;top:0;right:0`

Comment: I don't want to use CSS, I just want to try using bootstrap so I just want to know if there is anything in bootstrap that I can do that is similar to what you said

Comment: then simply read this : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/. Also bootrap is not supposed to provide ALL the different ways to do things, they provide the necessary/common things then you will for sure need your own style.

Comment: ... I have already read that part and it only show top bottom left right, I thought maybe I could do something like class="fixed-top-right"> but doesn't work

Comment: it's almost impossible to design a site without applying some custom CSS, it doesn't even makes sense...

Comment: @CalvinNunes I am currently trying to download my view as word document but the css is not applied so I just want to check if bootstrap work in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .pull-right class on your img tag to place your image on the right side like this:

```
<div id ="test">
    @foreach($data3 as $currentUser)
        <img class="pull-right" src="{{ url('images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}">
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Did you change your test div width? You can check my pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzVPXp

Comment: Nope, I didn't assign any styles for this div so there shouldn't be any problems, sorry for the late reply

Comment: I found the problem, it was the cause of another styles